# Android C/C++ native calls Java APIs

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, native-code, jnienv

There are lots of examples that Android C/C++ native calls Java APIs.
However, all of these examples I have read are the Android Java APIs call native
first and then the native calls other Java APIs by using the passed JNI-ENV.

Without the passed JNI-ENV, how can the C/C++ get it?
Is it possible that C/C++ native calls Java APIs  without JNI-ENV?

Can you give an example or a link for it if it is possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Checked this : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#wp9502 ?

Comment: I did try "JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);" and it did create a JVM. My Java APIs code can run on the JVM. However, Log.x (i, d, e..) inside the APIs cannot be run. The error message from logcat is "No implemention found for native Landroid/util/Log;.println_native(IILjava/lang/String;java/lang/String;)I"

Comment: Another big problem is that my Java APIs cannot use other Java Class to create an instance. For example, I get error message "No Implementation found for native Landroid/os/Binder;.init()V" when the Java API tries to create an instance from other class like this.
FileManager fm = new FileManager(null);

It seems the JVM created by JNI_CreateJavaVM() is missing some thing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to include `jni.h` first. This brings a ton of useful calls; with newer android releases you'll also need `JniInvocation.h`. To enable this:

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ${JNI_H_INCLUDE}
```

That certainly works with source tree, not sure about NDK, but should be fine, too.

Second, pretty important thing is to have proper **signal chain** lib selected. Art or Dalvik will load libsigchain.so, which is a stub and `abort()`s every time any of its methods are being called. On Android it's done with a little hack: local symbols are being exported to global symbol table, so that Art picks exec's symbols instead of loading shared lib. Here's how it's done:

```
# Enable native helper calls
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += libnativehelper

# Include all of the Android's libsigchain symbols
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += libsigchain

# Export only libsigchain symbols to global symbol table.
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += \
    -Wl,--export-dynamic \
    -Wl,--version-script,art/sigchainlib/version-script.txt
```

Link your executable now. Double check that the required symbols are indeed exported:

```
% readelf -a <output_binary> | grep InitializeSignalChain
654: 0002cab1   211 FUNC    GLOBAL PROTECTED   12 InitializeSignalChain
```

Done? things get simpler now:

1. Initialize the JNI (so that your code uses proper VM)

   ```
   JniInvocation invocation;
   if (invocation.Init(nullptr)) return;
   ```
2. Create JavaVM:

   ```
   JavaVM* vm;
   JNIEnv* env;
   JavaVMInitArgs* args;

   args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_4;  // _5, _6
   args.options = nullptr;
   args.nOptions = 0;
   args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;

   if (JNI_CreateJavaVM(&vm, &env, &args) < 0) return;
   ```
3. At this point your `vm` and `env` are ready to use. have fun.
4. Check for exceptions, if any

   ```
   if (env->ExceptionCheck()) {
       // ...
   }
   ```
5. When you're done, clean up

   ```
   vm->DetachCurrentThread();
   vm->DestroyJavaVM();
   ```

More interesting stuff can be found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libnativehelper/+/idea133/include/nativehelper/jni.h) and [DalvikVM Main](https://github.com/TaintDroid/android_platform_dalvik/blob/master/dalvikvm/Main.cpp) is probably the best source of knowledge. Good luck!